# Smallest positive integer that is divisble by 2, 3 and 5 and that is also a perfect square and perfect cube

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

My son is having this problem:

> Smallest positive integer that is divisible by $2$, $3$ and $5$, and that is also a perfect square and perfect cube.

He was busy using Excel, but I thought: Isn't there a faster way?

Comment: $$(2\cdot3\cdot5)^{6m}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee:  Since he said "smallest", my answer would be $(2\cdot 3\cdot 5)^6$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is an integer, then

- $n^2$ is a perfect square
- $n^3$ is a perfect cube

An integer that has both these properties is $n^{2\cdot 3}=n^{6}$, since $$n^{6}=\underset{\color{red}{\text{square}}}{\underbrace{(n^{3})^\color{red}{2}}}=\underset{\color{green}{\text{cube}}}{\underbrace{(n^{2})^\color{green}{3}}}$$ You also want this to be divisible by $2,3,5$, these are prime numbers so the smallest non-zero such number is $$(2\cdot 3\cdot 5)^6=30^6=729 000 000$$

Answer (score 2):

Since number has to be divisible by $2,3,5$ therefore it should be divisible by $30$. 
Since you want a perfect square and a perfect cube therefore your number should be of the form $30^{6t}$ . Where t is the integral number satisfying all such conditions.
In your case $t=1$ , therefore answer is $30^6$.

Comment: It took me a long time to edit , I could have posted it before lab bhattacharjee.

Comment: Thanks for upvote , next time I will try my best not to delay.